# Display text using thymeleaf exactly as it would be displayed in a text file.txt

Tags: java, spring-mvc, text, thymeleaf, ascii

So I'm using Spring with Thymeleaf and I have an ASCII generator that takes an image and turns it into ASCII chars. The chars are:

```
 .,:ilwW#MW&8%B@$
```

And after the conversion I want to display the image to the screen using Thymeleaf.
The text gets formatted well and turned into a String. When I write that string to a .txt file I get the expected output, but when I do it using Thymeleaf I get something else. I should get an equal amounts of characters on each line, but that's not the case with Thymeleaf, and instead I get the characters, but the newline doesn't seem to work. My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

public class ImageToAsciiConverter {

public static synchronized String convertImageToAscii(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ImagePlus image = new ImagePlus("Image", ImageIO.read(in));
    return new ImageToAsciiConverter().process(image);
}

// Processes the image pixel by pixel and sets appropriate ASCII chars for every
// pixel value. Returns a string containing the ASCII picture.
private String process(ImagePlus image) {
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor = image.getProcessor();
    imageProcessor.setInterpolate(true);
    ImagePlus imp = new ImagePlus("", imageProcessor.resize(300, 300));
    int[] size = imp.getDimensions();
    int width = size[0], height = size[1];
    ImageToAsciiUtil util = new ImageToAsciiUtil();
    return IntStream.range(0, width * height)
            .parallel()
            .map(i -> i % width != 0 ? util.convertToBrightness(imp.getPixel((i % width), (i / width))) : -1)
            .mapToObj(i -> i == -1 ? "\n" : util.getAsciiSymbol(i))
            .sequential()
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

/**
 * Utility class for converting images to ASCII characters.
 */
private static class ImageToAsciiUtil {

    /**
     * @param arr the array containing pixel RGB data.
     * @return Returns the averaged RGB value. (( R + G + B ) / 3 )
     */
    private int convertToBrightness(int[] arr) {
        return ((arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]) / 3);
    }

    /**
     * @param s  the value to be changed
     * @param a1 lower range of s.
     * @param a2 upper range of s.
     * @param b1 new lower range.
     * @param b2 new upper range.
     * @return Returns s with values ranging from b1 to b2.
     */
    private float map(float s, float a1, float a2, float b1, float b2) {
        return b1 + (s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1);
    }

    /**
     * .,:ilwW#MW&8%B@$
     * 
     * @param brightness The pixel brightness that's going to be associated with a
     *                   symbol.
     * @return Returns the ASCII symbol associated with the provided brightness.
     */
    private String getAsciiSymbol(int brightness) {
        String ASCII = " .,:ilwW#MW&8%B@$";
        String s = String.valueOf(ASCII.charAt((int) map(brightness, 0, 255, 0, ASCII.length() - 1)));
        return s + s + s;
    }
}

}
```

I've tried:

```
        <p th:text="${ascii}"></p>
        <p th:utext="${ascii}"></p>
```

And I've also tried different ways to issue a new line in HTML like:

```
<br/>
&#13
&#10
```

And I've tried editing the CSS too. Still different amount of characters on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured it out.
The problem was that I was using a font that is not monospaced. I changed the CSS property to:

```
font-family: monospace;
```

and then I removed the space character in the ASCII choices, because it wasn't being rendered and now it works as expected.

Comment: You can keep the whitespace if you also add `white-space: pre;` (and probably remove whatever you are using to add line breaks).